# How can I style the contents of a column in a dgrid, but not the column header?

Tags: javascript, css, dgrid

I've created a dgrid to work with a webmap I've created through ESRI's Javascript API.  The dgrid is working fine, but I want it to be more apparent to users that they can click on a cell in the first column to pan to that particular record on the map.  I've added a line to the CSS to style the text in the first column to blue with an underline, but it applies the style to the header in addition to the cell contents.  I'd like to leave the header unstyled while styling the contents of the columns.  Is this possible?

Sorry, I should have been more specific.  This isn't a table, it's a dojo dgrid.  An example of what I'm using is this: http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/samples/fl_dgrid/.  Users can click on a cell in the first column to pan to a feature, but there's nothing showing that that cell is clickable (hence why I want to style it).

The CSS I added to style the first column is as follows:

```
#grid { height: 100%; }
.dgrid { border: none; }
.field-id { cursor: pointer; 
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:blue;
}
```

Comment: how are you defining the header with `<th>` or the first `<td>` ... additional show your line fo CSS

Comment: as suggested by danko, make use of `<thead>` and ´<th>´ child elements so that you can target only the "content" cells with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this in your css:

```
td.field-id { cursor: pointer; 
  text-decoration:underline;
  color:blue;
}
```

With this you make more specific your selector then it only affects the `td` with class `field-id` not the `th` with that class.

Answer (score 0):

what they say is correct, have a look at this [Table ccs3](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_color)

Comment: this should be a comment